# Github Actions - create a fast running action

Tags: docker, github-actions, github-package-registry, docker-repository

I am creating a github docker container action that involves a number of dependencies python, node, pypi packages, and npm packages.  In order to speed up the action I move a lot of the dependency installation from the entrypoint to the Dockerfile.  Now my action is running really fast, but takes a really long time to build the action everytime.

Is there a way that the action can be pre-built, or do I need to publish my actions docker image to a repository somewhere and feed FROM my custom image?

For Reference, here is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3

LABEL "com.github.actions.name"="kedro-action"
LABEL "com.github.actions.description"="A Github Action to run kedro commands"
LABEL "com.github.actions.icon"="it-branch"
LABEL "com.github.actions.color"="black"

LABEL "repository"="http://github.com/WaylonWalker/kedro-action"
LABEL "maintainer"="Waylon Walker <waylon@waylonwalker.com>"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y jq

ENV PYENV_ROOT /root/.pyenv
ENV PATH $PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH
RUN curl -L https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/raw/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash

### INSTALL PYTHON ###
RUN pyenv install 3.7.6
RUN pyenv global 3.7.6
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install kedro
RUN pip install kedro-viz

### INSTALL NODEJS ###
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install nodejs -y

### CLONE KEDRO-STATIC-VIZ ###
RUN mkdir ~/build_dir && cd ~/build_dir
RUN git clone https://github.com/WaylonWalker/kedro-static-viz.git
RUN cd kedro-static-viz
RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli
RUN cd kedro-static-viz && npm install && npm audit fix


ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can prebuild the Docker image for your action and then in the `action.yml` file you specify the prebuilt image instead of `Dockerfile`. See the documentation [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/building-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#examples-using-dockerfile-in-your-repository).

This is an example for one of my actions that is [prebuilt here](https://hub.docker.com/r/peterevans/dockerhub-description).

```
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'docker://peterevans/dockerhub-description:2.1.0'
```

Comment: Absolutely please do this! It maddens me how github have made it so unclear that people should be publishing images not dockerfiles for their actions.

One small thing. You should rebuild the image every now and then to pull down the newest OS packages which will fix security vulnerabilities.