# How to prevent GitHub actions from always rebuilding my Dockerfile

Tags: docker, github-actions

I have an action.yml file and a Dockerfile in repository A like this:

## Repository A

### action.yml

```
[...]
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'
[...]
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM hello-world
# do something
```

Now in repository B, I use the action and the Dockerfile:

## Repository B

### .github/workflows/hello.yml

```
name: hello
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: username/repoa@master
```

My point of using the Dockerfile in repository A is, among other things:

1. that the GitHub action log is not cluttered with preparation steps which have no relation to the action in repository B
2. so that it only builds when username/repoa is updated, not when username/repob is updated, because the Dockerfile didn't change.

However in practice, GitHub will happily rebuild the Dockerfile everytime I commit to username/repob and clutter the GitHub action logs with it.

How can I tell GitHub to only build the Dockerfile when repository A is updated and keep it out of the action logs?

Comment: Replace `image: Dockerfile` with `image: a docker URL`, as in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60679692  Voting to close as a duplicate, even though this is honestly a much better worded question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Actions - create a fast running action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675844/github-actions-create-a-fast-running-action)

Comment: @dannysauer: Thanks for the link! However I'm not certain if the answer to the other question is the same as my use case. If I understand it correctly, that answer is to set up a separate step to upload the image to a Docker registry such as DockerHub, however my optimal solution would be for GitHub to handle that by itself in the background using it's own caches.

Answer (score 0):

Github Workflows create a new machine to run a job, this means that when Github Actions build your image, you need to store this image in a registry or something and use this stored image to create another `step`.

You need to improve your `action.yml` to build and store the image and create another `action2.yml` to say what to do with your container.

Comment: That's not how actions work.  The action.yml defines what to do when the repo is used as an action.